# Having issues migrating data with attachments in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, sharepoint-2007, dao, attachment-field

All,

I have an MS Access database that has some file attachments that I need to programmatically copy to another MS Access table (both tables are linked tables to a SharePoint 2007 list).  I have the following code.

```
Private Sub AddAttachments(rsSource As Recordset, rsDest As Recordset)
    Dim rs2Source As Recordset2
    Dim rs2Dest As Recordset2
    Set rs2Source = rsSource.Fields!Attachments.Value
    Set rs2Dest = rsDest.Fields("Attachments").Value
    rs2Source.MoveFirst
    If Not (rs2Source.BOF And rs2Source.EOF) Then
        While Not rs2Source.EOF
            rs2Dest.AddNew
            rs2Dest!FileData = rs2Source!FileData
            rs2Dest.Update
            rs2Source.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    Set rs2Source = Nothing
    Set rs2Dest = Nothing
End Sub
```

My issue is that when it gets to rs2Dest!FileData = rs2Source!FileData, it keeps giving me an Invalid Argument error.  So, if what I am trying to do is possible, how can I adjust my code to read the attachment data from one list and import it into the other list (both linked as linked-tables in an instance of MS Access).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

Here is the clunky solution I came up with in case it helps someone else.

First, I needed to access the URLmon library's URLDownloadToFileA function.

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFileA Lib "urlmon" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szfilename As String, ByVal dwreserved As Long, ByVal ipfnCB As Long) As Long
```

Then, I would use this library to download the file to my disk, upload from my disk, and delete the temporarily stored file as follows:

```
Private Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
    DownloadFile = (URLDownloadToFileA(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0) = 0)
End Function

Private Function GetRight(strText As String, FindText As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Len(strText) - Len(FindText) + 1 To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(strText, i, Len(FindText)) = FindText Then
            GetRight = Mid(strText, i + 1, Len(strText))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Private Sub AddAttachments(rsSource As Recordset, rsDest As Recordset)
    Dim rs2Source As Recordset2
    Dim rs2Dest As Recordset2
    Set rs2Source = rsSource.Fields!Attachments.Value
    Set rs2Dest = rsDest.Fields("Attachments").Value
    Dim strDownload As String
    Dim strTemp As String
    strTemp = Environ$("TEMP")
    If Not (rs2Source.BOF And rs2Source.EOF) Then
        rs2Source.MoveFirst
        If Not (rs2Source.BOF And rs2Source.EOF) Then
            While Not rs2Source.EOF
                rs2Dest.AddNew
                'rs2Dest.Update
                'rs2Dest.MoveLast
                'rs2Dest.Edit
                strDownload = strTemp & "\" & GetRight(rs2Source!FileURL, "/")
                Debug.Print DownloadFile(rs2Source!FileURL, strDownload)
                rs2Dest.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile strDownload
                rs2Dest.Update
                rs2Source.MoveNext
                Kill strDownload 'delete the temporarily stored file
            Wend
        End If
    End If
    Set rs2Source = Nothing
    Set rs2Dest = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm sure there's an easier way, but this seem to work for my purposes (albeit in a clunky fashion that is only fitting for the likes of VBA).